# Django multiple "daisy-chained" models

Tags: django

I have five "connected" models: Book, Chapter, Page, Paragraph, Line. They are all connected by a chain of foreign keys in the sense that

- Line has a foreign key linking it to Paragraph
- Paragraph has a foreign key linking it to Page
- Page has a foreign key linking it to Chapter
- Chapter has a foreign key linking it to Book

Basically, 5 tables, 4 one-to-many relationships.

I would like to display a tree of nested lists. I know how to do it for just Book and Chapter (using regroup) but when I need to "dig deeper" I'm stuck.

Answer (score 0):

This has nothing to do with `regroup`, you just need to use the reverse relationships. I'd imagine this might be very heavy load on the template renderer though and you'll probably need to look into ways to make this perform better.

```
{% for chapter in book.chapter_set.all %}
    {% for page in chapter.page_set.all %}    
        {% for paragraph in page.paragraph_set.all %}        
            {% for line in paragraph.line_set.all %}
            {% endfor %}        
        {% endfor %}    
    {% endfor %}
{% endfor %}
```